# Physics: Columbs Law Over a Distance

Tags: physics

I have a superposition of charges problem, and the following details are important to problem.  I have a charge $q_1=6\ \mathrm{\mu C}$ located at the origin $(0,0)$, in a Cartesian coordinate system in which the metrics of the set are in meters.  I have as well another charge at the point $(.03,0)$, and the charge has a value of $q_2 = 1.50 \ \mathrm{\mu C}$. Finally I have a charge stationed at the point $(.05,0)$, and the charge has a charge of $q_3 = -2.00 \ \mathrm{\mu C}$

### My Attempt

### My Question is How to find the net force acting on charge 1.

To attempt the problem I have done the following:
\begin{align*}
F_{net_{q_1}}&= F_{21}+F_{31} \\
F_{net_{q_1}} &= k \ \cdot \ 6.00 \mathrm{\mu C} \ \cdot[\frac{1.50 \mathrm{\mu C}}{(.03 \mathrm{m})^2}-\frac{2.00 \mathrm{\mu C}}{(.02 \mathrm{m})^2}] \\
F_{net_{q_1}} &= 46.7 \mathrm{N}
\end{align*}

Comment: This probably should be posted on Physics.SE.

Comment: @TedShifrin Probably knock it down for being homework problems.

Comment: Well, we don't like homework problems with little effort and *no explanation* on Math.SE either.

Comment: @TedShifrin How is there little explanation I said its a columb law problem and to find the net force acting on charge 1. I even gave details on the problem background.

Comment: I don’t see a question here. What is it that you’d like someone to tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The net force should be

\begin{align*}
F_{net_{q_1}} &= k \ \cdot \ 6.00 \mathrm{\mu C} \ \cdot[\frac{1.50 \mathrm{\mu C}}{(.03 \mathrm{m})^2}-\frac{2.00 \mathrm{\mu C}}{(.05 \mathrm{m})^2}] 
\end{align*}

Use 0.05 instead of 0.02 for the second distance.